# What is the verbかけ- form used ? If any examples then please explain

Tags: grammar, keigo

Which sentence is correct for **example**,"They didn't call me/invited me for the meeting!"

I tried to making below sentences but i am not sure which one is correct(or no one):

- 私を会議に招待していません。/ 私を会議に呼びませんでした。
- 私を会議に**呼びかけ**ませんでした。

  What is the **verb + かけ** form? in which case we can use?
  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural (and also the easiest) way to express this would be:

- 私は会議に呼ばれませんでした

...using the passive voice.

会議に呼びませんでした is grammatically correct as a matter-of-factly statement, but it would sound fairly indifferent and unnatural. If you want to use the active voice, please remember there is a set of "subsidiary verbs of favor" in Japanese.

- 会議に呼んでいただけませんでした。
- 会議に呼んでくれなかった。(in not-so-formal settings)

呼びかける is a compound verb rather than a form of 呼ぶ. It is closer to "to call for" or "to address", and it is not a suitable word in this situation. The object of 呼びかける is not a person but 協力, 参加, 寄付, etc. As for the meaning of かける itself, please see: [Correct use of かけて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38193/5010)

Answer (score 2):

[呼びかける](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B3%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) is a compound verb of [呼びます](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%91%BC%E3%81%B6) and [かけます](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%8E%9B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) rather than a かけ form of a verb.

I also think more context to your question is necessary. Has the meeting already happened or is it in the future? To me, in English, "call me for the meeting" and "invite me to the meeting" have different meanings.

"They didn't call me for the meeting" could imply that you would have joined the meeting by phone as opposed to in person and you were expecting the people at the meeting to call you. It could also mean that you were not contacted by phone and asked to attend the meeting, ahead of the meeting time.

"They didn't invite me to the meeting" sounds like you expected to attend the meeting, but knew in advance of the meeting that you would not be attending, by phone or in person.

Comment: @katatahiti: I expected to be in the meeting, but in advance i knew that i am not invited yet!