# Meaning of 崩れかける

Tags: translation, verbs, subsidiary-verbs

I'm having some difficulties understanding the construction `崩れかけた` in

> 博士たちは崩れかけた門をくぐり、中へ入っていった。

I couldn't find it as a single word, so I take it is constructed from `崩れる` and `かける`. My guess is that it's the stem form of `崩れる` joined with `かける` (equivalent to the て form to join to verbs), but I'm not sure.

`崩れる` means something like collapsed so I was thinking it referred to a collapsed gate. I don't know what `かける` adds to this though...

Can someone shine some light on this?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38193/correct-use-of-かけて

Answer (score 9, accepted):

かける can be used as an subsidiary verb to mean "start to [verb]", so 崩れかけた is indeed the 連用形 *ren'yōkei* (*masu*-stem) of 崩れる followed by かけた.

崩れかけた門 means "a gate, which has started to break down / deteriorate". Of course you would usually translate this more directly, maybe (for lack of a better word) "deteriorating / wrecked gate".

See for example

- [When is <verb stem>+かける's meaning to start and leave unfinished?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69182/1628)
- [Correct use of かけて](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38193/1628)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this at all. I'm a bit surprised it doesn't appear in either "A Dictionary of Basic/Intermidiate Japanese Grammar" though.

Comment: ＠Jak I couldn't seem to find it in the "A Dictionary of Japanese Grammar" books either. However I sometimes like to check this Wikipedia page which does have it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#Auxiliary_verbs

Comment: It [appears in Jim Breen's EDICT](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MDJ%A4%AB%A4%B1%A4%EB), which is the basis of pretty much every online J->E dictionary out there.  I was doing subtitles for a concert video more than three years ago. 壊れかけた現実 came up in a song and I found in the above that it must be "reality that's on the verge of breaking" or "started to break".  I have all three of those grammar books:--basic, intermediate, advanced--but didn't need them for this.

Comment: Added comment: This <verb stem> + かける pattern is very common in both modern spoken and written Japanese. Worth understanding.